# Add JSON object in Body of API Gateway to Kinesis proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-kinesis

I have configured API gateway as a Kinesis proxy as described in [Amazon’s tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-kinesis.html) for putting record into Kinesis stream.

The HTTP headers for integration request are:

- `stream-name` is mapped to `method.request.header.stream-name`
- `partition-key` is mapped to `method.request.header.partition-key`
- `Content-Type` is mapped to `application/x-amz-json-1.1`

The body mapping template for content-type `application/json` looks like:

```
{
    "StreamName": "$input.params('stream-name')",
    "PartitionKey": "$input.params('partition-key')",
    "Data": "$util.base64Encode({"rows": "$input.json('$')", "uuid": "$input.params('uuid')"})"
}
```

The data comes in as a JSON-request payload. We should add a `uuid` parameter as a JSON-object key into the data-payload for Kinesis, but the encoded data being sent to Kinesis isn’t a JSON object.

It is required to add a parameter `uuid` as a json-object key into the data-payload for kinesis. The problem I am facing is, that encoded data sent to kinesis is not a JSON object.

The data I expect to be sent to Kinesis should be a JSON object:

```
{
 "rows": [{"id": 1, "name": "a"}, {"id": 2, "name": "b"}],
 "uuid": "0001"
}
```

But the actual data sent to Kinesis looks like:

```
{
 rows=[{"id": 1, "name": "a"}, {"id": 2, "name": "b"}],
 uuid=0001
}
```

How can I send a JSON object from API gateway to Kinesis? I have been experimenting with `$util.parseJson` but couldn't find a solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes in velocity templates

```
#set($event =  "{
  ""rows"": ""$input.json('$')"",
  ""uuid"": ""$input.params('uuid')"",
}")
{
   "StreamName": "$input.params('stream-name')",  
   "Data": "$util.base64Encode($event)",  
   "PartitionKey": "$input.params('partition-key')"
}
```

Here is a similar question on the aws forums for sending data to kinesis through api gateway https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=233060